# In regards to scraping, how do I prevent blank lists from being created in a for loop?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

```
import urllib.request
import bs4 as bs

sauce = urllib.request.urlopen('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_S%26P_500_companies').read().decode()
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(sauce, 'lxml')

soup.th.decompose()

table = soup.find('table')
trows = soup.find_all('tr')

for trow in trows:
    td = trow.find_all('td')
    row = [x.text for x in td]
    print(row)
```

I've been playing around with scraping web pages and tables seem to be the hardest. However, I was able to create a list of rows of the table data pretty nicely. The problem is there is a blank list that is printed because of the table header `<th>`. This creates a problem when I only want to print `row[0]` and `row[1]` because it returns this `"IndexError: list index out of range"`. I know this is because `<th>` falls under `<tr>` but has no `<td>`.

After looking through the bs4 documentation I tried using `.decompose()` to remove the `<th>` headers to no avail. An empty list is still produced. Any help on this matter would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just have it skip when it gets to an empty row, in your case when your row returns `[]`

```
for trow in trows:
    td = trow.find_all('td')
    row = [x.text for x in td]

    if row == []:
        continue

    print(row)
```

I'll also point out too, that I hate trying to parse tables by doing the whole search for `<table>`, `<tr>`, `<td>`, etc. While sometimes is necesary, but whenever I see a `<table>` tag, I'll try Pandas first, and see if it can give me relatively something I want. I'd rather do a little work manipulating a dataframe, than a lot of work working through nested tags.

```
import urllib.request
import pandas as pd

sauce = urllib.request.urlopen('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_S%26P_500_companies').read().decode()

tables = pd.read_html(sauce)
```

So `.read_html()` will return a list of dataframes. In the case here, theres 2. So to view them, just do `print (tables[0])` or `print (tables[1])`

Comment: thanks a lot! I was able to display the two columns I wanted using  `print(tables[['Security', 'Symbol']])` this is a much cleaner way. I also noticed in your profile you're part of the GIS community. That is actually why I'm learning python. Do you have any recommendations on what areas of python I should focus on in regards to GIS? Thanks again.

Comment: I was just sort of playing around with it to try different things. And now as it turns out, doing quite a bit of clustering and whatnot with geocodes for a project at work. The few things I've played with are: [OSMnx](https://github.com/gboeing/osmnx), [geopy](https://pypi.org/project/geopy/) and [basemap](https://matplotlib.org/basemap/api/basemap_api.html)